# How to associate table column with another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, model-associations

So basically I like to know what association i need to link my routes table with employees table. I have a routes table with an employees column (array type) which holds employee id's. I also have an employee table that has (first_name, last_name, phone_number).

A `has_many :employees, foreign_key: :employees, class_name: :Employee` does not work and gives an error. Any ideas?

This error is given

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column employees.employees does not exist)
LINE 1: SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."emp...
```

Comment: You are fighting rails conventions with this approach.  Rails would prefer a join table -- route_employees and then you can do has_many through. If you feel like bleeding a bit you can investigate using https://github.com/marshall-lee/has_array_of or at least see how they are attempting to do it.

Comment: Its not just the conventions - ActiveRecord assocations don't work with array columns at all. They expect you to actually use a relational database the way it was designed to be used - by using tables and foreign keys to discribe the relations between the tables. Array columns are a specialized tool and should not be how you normally construct your schema.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using an array column here is a just bad idea:

- Violates first normal form.
- Doesn't let you use foreign keys to maintain referential integrity.
- Doesn't work with ActiveRecord assocations that expect you to model your data in a sane way.
- You will need to write queries by hand.

Instead you most likely want is a [self-referential assocation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins):

```ruby
class AddManagerToEmployees < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_reference :employees, :manager, 
       null: true, 
       foreign_key: { to_table: :employees }
  end
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :manager, 
    class_name: 'Employee'
  has_many   :subordinates, 
    class_name: 'Employee',
    foreign_key: :manager_id
end
```

If the manager-employee relation should be many to many instead of one to many use a join table.